# How to remove Journal of LaTEX class above the title in IEEETrans?

Tags: ieeetran

This is what I have in the pdf when I print my manuscript above the title. How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: example please!

Comment: I just want to say, the results of searching for papers with "Journal of Latex class files" on it was pretty hilarious.

Answer (score 6):

This is the expected behavior for `IEEEtran` class when using the `article` option.

The `IEEETran` class also provides the `conference` option, which eliminates this header, as well as the initial drop cap.

So, if you want to **comply** with IEEE *article* standards, do nothing.

On the other hand, if you want to just remove it ---at the expense of also losing the drop cap--- and continue within IEEE specifications, try the *conference* version (e.g. `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`)

Comment: What if the user likes the `IEEEtran` class / article format and style, but wants to use it for a different purpose?

Comment: Sure, that could be it.  If that would be the case, you just need to control it with `\markboth{}{}`, as described in the template file (see Guido's answer).

Answer (score 6):

The running heads are controlled by

```
\markboth{PUBLICATION INFO}{AUTHOR(S) INFO}
```

See section C, page 5 of the `IEEEtran` manual ("how to Use the IEEEtran LaTeX Class"). To see the documentation use `texdoc ieeetran` from the terminal or command line.

A simple way to remove it is `\markboth{}{}`.